# Where are ALL GitLab's user data stored?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm learning to find my way through a GitLab CE installation, in anticipation of automating its deployment into our infrastructure. We codify our deployments so that we can easily redeploy or upgrade: bytes are either put in place by the deployment process *or* mounted in as a file share. We would still totally use the GitLab Omnibus installer (essentially `apt-get install gitlab-ce`), but then copy our own data and configuration files in place before startup. For this I need to know all user data locations (things that the installer inherently doesn't have). I've read through a lot of the documentation, and I've seen the [GitLab directory structure](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/structure.html). But this document seems to be incomplete (I may be wrong).

This is what I assembled so far: (some overlap here)

- `"/etc/gitlab"`
- `"/home/git/.ssh"`
- `"/home/git/gitlab"`
- `"/home/git/gitlab-shell"`
- `"/home/git/repositories"`
- `git_data_dirs`
- `gitlab_rails['shared_path']`
- `gitlab_rails['uploads_directory']`
- `nginx['ssl_certificate']`
- `nginx['ssl_certificate_key']`
- `"/var/log/gitlab"` (for completeness sake; debatable whether this is user data)

So my question is *either* for a definitive list, or help with improving my list above. Thank you.

Comment: This question does not really have anything to do with *programming*.

Comment: I find that a totally fair point. I normally _do_ turn to Stack Overflow for programming questions. This time I followed [the suggestion on the site of GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/getting-help/#technical-support) to ask here. And with existing tags like `gitlab` and `gitlab-omnibus` you would not expect too much programming questions anyway, no?

Comment: Given that people can make code contributions to gitlab, my guess is that those tags might be necessary for that purpose. I don't think GitLab's suggestion to use SO as if it were a tech-support (they do redirect from that location in their page) site is valid and might show a slight misunderstanding on their part, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I don't entirely disagree with that reasoning. But there's plenty of questions and answers on Stack Overflow that aren't strictly programming. Notably a non-trivial amount of configuration and setup questions about GitLab. And also a large amount of highly popular questions about Git. Again, I can see your point, I just hope we're not closing my question here over the matter. That would also not solve the root problem, which is that GitLab would have to change their approach, which is very out of my control.

Comment: When I've looked at Git questions, they're usually about how to use a specific command or how to get out of some hole someone dug him/herself into with a programming-related tool. I'm sure a few may not necessarily be on that, and that someone could argue the same about GitLab, but this particular question (to me) looks more about trying to understand how GL itself is set-up/configured internally, etc. -something that should arguably be better addressed by their documentation.

Comment: Do you have suggestions to rephrase the question to better fit the format of Stack Overflow? I don't think the criterion is that I should dig myself into a hole before asking this question.

Comment: This is meant more as something "to think about", but perhaps instead of making a post that boils down to "I need help finding/building single authoritative document", which might be more appropriate for the documentation site, you should focus more on the fact that you're writing a program that needs to access certain GL resources and you have not found them at the locations specified by their documentation? Also note that GL does have one of those one-click-installs, so it's not clear why you feel you need to write a program to manage installs/deployments, and so on.